# JODconverter: only install pdf generator from openoffice

Tags: java, pdf, export, openoffice-writer, jodconverter

I am using JODConverter together with openoffice in a small java application. I have only installed the writer component (takes about 250mb of space). My question now is, whether I can trim openoffice down so that only the PDF generator is being installed or at least a more slim version of openoffice? Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but in fact I was looking for the exact same thing. I found on the official Google Code website that you really really need the entire installation.
https://code.google.com/p/jodconverter/wiki/FAQ